# Hibernate ignores @Lock(PESSIMISTIC_WRITE) when not querying whole entity

Tags: hibernate

I have a Car entity and a CarRepository. Before I insert new cars I check if there is already a car with for the UUID:

```java
public interface CarRepository extends JpaRepository<Car, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT c.uuid FROM Car c WHERE c.uuid = :uuid")
    @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
    Optional<UUID> findByUuid(final String uuid)
}
```

When I turn on logging for Hibernate I see that there is a plain select executed without pessimistic locking.

If I change my query to

```java
@Query("SELECT c FROM Car c WHERE c.uuid = :uuid")
@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
Optional<Car> findByUuid(final String uuid)
```

the executed  select statement contains the pessimistic locking clause just as intended. For performance reasons I'm preferring the first approach as not all fields are loaded. How can I achieve pessimistic locking with the first approach?